# Looking for network surveillance tool

Tags: networking, software-recommendation, security, users, network-bridge

I sometimes use / test software that cannot be found in the apt tree. The software comes from all over the internet. When executing the software I create an extra user for this particular software and then execute this software with it. This way I prevent the software from accessing unwanted areas of my system.

What now would be nice, would be to have a tool that surveils the network traffic of a specefic user or my specefic program. So maybe a possiblity to create a TAP just for this user and bridge it to eth0 and connect Wireshark to the TAP device.

Is that possible? Is there a ready-to-use technique or software for that? That this "interception" technique have a special name?

Comment: divert-sockets and filters or tap interfaces are what you want.  sockets have no user affinity though, so you need to track process to socket maps too.  tap interfaces are the easiest way.

Comment: Thanks for pointing on TAP. Would you know any how to?

Comment: I'm sure Google does.

Answer (score 1):

You could just test it in a virtual box of Ubuntu. That way you would have full control of network seting and there is also minimal risk of corruption